# Midpoint between two coordinates that are vertically aligned

Tags: calculus

I know how to find a midpoint between two points that lay on the same Y-axis value, like (10,5) and (12,5) but what about finding a midpoint between points that are vertically aligned so their both X and Y values are different. Like in this picture:

[image]

Can someone please help me find formula for finding that midpoint?

Comment: Do the same for the x value as you were doing for the y value - take the average.

Comment: Where are the two points?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be vectors pointing to your two points. Then the point you are looking for is given by a simple average, $$\frac{\vec a+\vec b}{2}.$$